# Why are trailing lamdas in Kotlin not carried out in this "repeat" function (from Google Tutorial)?

Tags: kotlin

To preface, I'm not a professional, nor a student. I have been self teaching Python and JavaScript for very basic quality of life improvements and I'm working my way through the Google Developers "Kotlin Fundamentals" for something different. However I've reached trailing lambdas and the "repeat function" and gotten a bit confused.

Before using the repeat function, the tutorial code was functioning as expected:

```
main() {
val treatFunction = trickOrTreat(false) {"$it quarters"}
val trickFunction = trickOrTreat(true, null)
treatFunction()
trickFunction()
}

fun trickOrTreat(isTrick: Boolean, extraTreat: ((Int) -> String)?): () -> Unit {
    if(isTrick) {
    return trick
    } else {
        if (extraTreat != null) {
            println(extraTreat(5))
            }
            return treat
    }  
}

val trick: () -> Unit =  {
    println("No Treats!")
}

val treat: () -> Unit = {
    println("Have a treat!")
}
```

Which returned:

```
5 quarters
Have a treat!
No Treats!
```

But it then explains the "repeat" function and guides you to nest the treatFunction() inside a repeat function:

```
main() {
    val treatFunction = trickOrTreat(false) {"$it quarters"}
    val trickFunction = trickOrTreat(true, null)
    repeat(4) {
        treatFunction()
    }
    trickFunction()
}
```

Which returned:

```
5 quarters
Have a treat!
Have a treat!
Have a treat!
Have a treat!
No Treats!
```

This is the output that I was supposed to expect, but the guide doesn't explain - and I do not understand - why the trailing lambda "{$it quarters}" for the value "treatFunction" is not expressed in each iteration of the repeat function. e.g:

```
5 quarters
Have a treat!
5 quarters
Have a treat!
5 quarters
Have a treat!
5 quarters
Have a treat!
No Treats!
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many times you call `repeat` because `treatFunction` is already initialized by this moment and it's actually a reference to `treat` object. `println(extraTreat(5))` is invoked only during this initialization. When you run `treatFunction()` it is actually dereferenced to `treat()` that in turn doesn't contain `println(extraTreat(5))` logic.